# Check if Tree is BST using stack and inorder traversal

Tags: c++, stl, stack, binary-tree

Here is my code, but it is not producing any output.

```
stack < int > st;
bool func(Node * root) {
  if (root != NULL) {
    func(root -> left);
    st.push(root -> data);
    func(root -> right);
  }
  while (!st.empty()) {
    int upar = st.top();
    st.pop();
    if (upar > st.top()) {
      continue;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Please tell me what am I missing. I traced the code right but it is not showing the relevant result.

Answer (score 0):

What I see from your code is that your function `func()` is called recursively but its return value is never checked. It should be fine if it means to push stuff into a stack to create an in-order traversal, but you also included the while loop to check if the data are in ascending order. This is the problem.

The easiest fix I can think of is to break it into two:

```
stack < int > st;
void func(Node * root) {
  if (root != NULL) {
    func(root -> left);
    st.push(root -> data);
    func(root -> right);
  }
}
bool check(Node* root) {
  func(root);
  while (!st.empty()) {
    int upar = st.top();
    st.pop();
    if (upar > st.top()) {
      continue;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

but you have to check are you going to assume no duplicate entries in the BST, for you're using `upar > st.top()` instead of `>=`.

If you insist to combine the two into one function, you can consider to change `func()` to pass on upper or lower bound for the values in addition to the `Node*` so you can correspondingly check the left and right sub-tree. You can skip the use of stack all together in this case. But start with the root node and bound from negative infinity to positive infinity. When you do the recursion, you replace the `root->data` for upperbound on left tree and for lowerbound on right tree.